# search fields django admin with uppercase/lowercase

Tags: django, django-admin, django-admin-filters

In my Django admin app i have this code in admin.py:

```
search_fields = ["app_product_mapping", "id", "app__app_name", "product__product_name"]
```

I noticed that the search field is sensitive to Uppercase and Lowercase and I want to make it sensitive to all over.

How can I do that?
TNX!

Comment: Do you want to make it `case-insensitive` ?

Comment: yes. for exa: if i write 'rem' or 'rEm' -> i want to see 'Rem' result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was resolved - I changed in my DB the Collation type to 'utf16_unicode_520_ci' and it works!

Answer (score 0):

The search is already `case-insensitive`.

When somebody does a search in the admin search box, Django splits the search query into words and returns all objects that contain each of the words, **case-insensitive** (using the **icontains** lookup), where each word must be in at least one of search_fields. For example, if search_fields is set to **['first_name', 'last_name']** and a user searches for *john lennon*, Django will do the equivalent of this SQL **WHERE** clause:

```
WHERE (first_name ILIKE '%john%' OR last_name ILIKE '%john%')
AND (first_name ILIKE '%lennon%' OR last_name ILIKE '%lennon%')
```

Comment: Tnx for your comment. So how can I handle it?